# Elasticsearch Scan&scroll with JEST API

Tags: java, rest, lucene, elasticsearch

I am currently working with JEST:
https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest

Is it possible to do scan&scroll with this API?

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/search-type/

I am currently using the Search command:

```
Search search = new Search("{\"size\" : "+RESULT_SIZE+", \"query\":{\"match_all\":{}}}");
```

but am worried about large result sets. If you use the Search command for this how do you set the "search_type=scan&scroll=10m&size=50" arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:**

<strike>It doesn't appear that JEST currently supports the "Scan" search type:</strike> In a wicked fast turnaround, it appears that JEST now supports Scan type searches! Props to [@Ferhat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320202/ferhat-sobay) for the quick turnaround! [JEST - SearchType.java](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/src/main/java/io/searchbox/params/SearchType.java)

---

Have you considered just using the ElasticSearch Transport client?  I could understand if you like the JEST API a little better, but as new features roll out for ElasticSearch ([Exhibit A: ElasticSearch 0.90 is fantastic!](http://www.elasticsearch.org/2013/04/29/0-90-0-released/)), you'll get to have them as soon as they pop out instead of waiting for JEST to catch up.

My $0.02.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Stuck using http for this application.

Comment: I see, I see. Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance!

Answer (score 15):

> Is it possible to do scan&scroll with this API?

Yes it is. My implementation it's working  like this.

Start the scroll search on elastic search:

```
    public SearchResult startScrollSearch (String type, Long size) throws IOException {

            String query = ConfigurationFactory.loadElasticScript("my_es_search_script.json");

            Search search = new Search.Builder(query)
                                            // multiple index or types can be added.
                                            .addIndex("myIndex")
                                            .addType(type)
                                            .setParameter(Parameters.SIZE, size)
                                            .setParameter(Parameters.SCROLL, "1m")
                                            .build();

                SearchResult searchResult = EsClientConn.getJestClient().execute(search);
                return searchResult;

        }
```

SearchResult object will return the first (size) itens off the search as usual but will return to a scrollId parameter that is a reference to remain resultSet that elasticSearch keeps in memory for you. Parameters.SCROLL, will define the time that this search will be keeped on memory.

For read the scrollId:

```
scrollId = searchResult.getJsonObject().get("_scroll_id").getAsString();
```

For read more items from the resultSet you should use something like follow:

```
public JestResult readMoreFromSearch(String scrollId, Long size) throws IOException {

    SearchScroll scroll = new SearchScroll.Builder(scrollId, "1m")
                .setParameter(Parameters.SIZE, size).build();

        JestResult searchResult = EsClientConn.getJestClient().execute(scroll);
        return searchResult;

}
```

Don't forget that each time you read from the result set a new scrollId is returned from elastic.

Please tell me if you have any doubt.

Comment: Parameters.SIZE may not be required for subsequent scroll requests as given in the github link below . I tried with version 7.17.3 maven dependency.

Answer (score 8):

Agreed we need to catch up however please open an issue if you need a feature.

Please check https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/jest/src/test/java/io/searchbox/core/SearchScrollIntegrationTest.java at master

Comment: Is there any example for clearing a scroll? (PS: I know this post is SUPER old. I'd rather be using the ES client API, but stupid Google AppEngine hates it).

Comment: From the github link given above : 
`ClearScroll clearScroll = new ClearScroll.Builder().addScrollId(scrollId).build();
 JestResult clearResult = client.execute(clearScroll);`